# convert an anonymous user to a new user with signInWithRedirect in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm really confused about converting anonymous users.

If my sign in flow is with `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect` the anonymous user always disappears after the redirect back.

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth?authuser=0) say to use the following function:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential).then(function(user) {
  console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", user);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error upgrading anonymous account", error);
});
```

but the currentUser isn't the anonymous user anymore after `signInWithRedirect`... So how can I do this combined with `signInWithRedirect`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do linkWithRedirect on anonymous user directly. When do you need to call signInWithRedirect if you already have a anonymous user?

Comment: When the user wants to continue using a google account e.g

Comment: the docks don't say anything about linkWithRedirect....... Is. That really a possibility!!??

Comment: Check this one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking